# How can you tell if a user choose not to install a plug in?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, plugins, vbscript, activex

I am not sure the user is going to install the plug in.  They can choose not to install.  I need to know information like, install complete, or the user choose not to install.  Any ideas?

Thanks,
Grae

Comment: To anyone who reads this in the future.  I suggest this over the VBScript solutions which do the same thing.  VBScript and JavaScript are not as compatible as I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More context would be helpful in answering your question.

That said, if there's a particular plugin that you have in mind, you can do a post-install check* of simply trying to instantiate the object. [This article](http://www.sliceratwork.com/detect-installed-browser-plugins-using-javascript) has a pretty good description of what to do, but if you only care about IE and ActiveX plugins, then something like this should work well enough (**untested**):

```
function testPlugin(name)
{
    if (ActiveXObject)
    {
        try
        {
            return !!(new ActiveXObject(name));
        }
        catch (err) {}
    }
    return false;
}
​
```

and you could use that function to test whether or not, say, QuickTime is installed:

```
testPlugin('QuickTime.QuickTime');
```

---

*This will actually work at any time, not just after a possible plugin install

Comment: This is basically, what I used.  The one thing I would add is that the only way I know of to tell if the install is done, it wait for the unload.

Comment: The above code probably works, I call simular in the onunload.